# FTP - 530 Sorry, the maximum number of clients…?

Tags: ftp, maximum, clients

My problem is that my FTP work great, exept when i upload files on a particular client server!

on this server happen that some files are uploaded fine and others not, they stop while uploading at half of it's size, then this error is displayed:

> 530 Sorry, the maximum number of
>   clients (4) from your host are already
>   connected. Unable to make a
>   connection. Please try again.

Obviously this is not true, i'm the only one that is uploading!

Anyone had the same experience with this!?

PS: i have tried many different FTP, all display the same error or just hung up!

Thank's

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Some FTP clients open up a connection for transfer and a control connection.  That would tie up a minimum of two connections.  Many FTP clients will open up multiple connections during file transfer to speed things up -- uploading 10 files through separate connections at the same time rather than uploading one at a time.

I've also seen this behavior with Windows 7 and servers using more recent versions of pure-ftpd.  Connections on the server side never seem to close with Windows 7/pure-ftpd which leaves a number of them hanging until they time out.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of server in question **pure-ftpd**! what client i should use instead!? i have tried FileZilla, FireFTP and also some "pro" ftp's. thank's!

Comment: The issue appears to be related to Windows7 and pure-ftpd regardless of the client.  Downgrading pure-ftpd to an older release, I believe 1.0.21 solved it in one case.  Something in Windows7 doesn't acknowledge the TCP connection which leaves it open.  At some points, the transfer stalls and times out, leaving it open on the server.  Other times, the file is completely transferred, but, isn't acknowledged on Windows7 and pure-ftpd doesn't drop it.  We did try proftpd, but had similar issues.  Something in Windows7 doesn't like the TCP stack on some servers.

Comment: i'm running 3 machine, one with vista one with xp and one with nix! none of this work! anyway thank's to All.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux server; Connect to root files (ex: WinSCP program)

file edit: root/etc/proftpd.conf
Update and Restart Services > Ftp Server

```
MaxClients 30 "Sorry, this ftp server has reached its maximum user count (%m).  Please try again later"
    <Limit LOGIN>
      AllowAll
    </Limit>
    <Limit WRITE>
      AllowAll
    </Limit>

    <Directory incoming>
      <Limit STOR>
        AllowAll
      </Limit>
      <Limit WRITE READ>
        AllowAll
      </Limit>
    </Directory>
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, not sure why it's voted down. If the user is using ProFTP then this answer is correct. From the error message quoted in the first message, it does look like a ProFTP error message.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with that server, or because you're using a proxy server, or because you're behind NAT.

Comment: first of, tnx for responce! i just want know why this happen only with  some file!? :) and what i should do for circumvent this!?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I reached my disk space quota on a shared server. Deleting unnecessary files solved the issue.